# where to send daemon optional output so it's readable

Tags: bash, sockets, port, vowpalwabbit

My daemon has option

```
-r WhereShouldIOutputAdditionalData
```

daemon is listening on port 26542 and writes on the same port , I want additional data to output to 26542 as well, I tried using

```
-r /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/26542
```

and it doesn't work, When I do

```
> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/26542
```

I get connection refused. Deamon that I use: vowpal_wabbit, machine learning library.Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "writes on the same port" you mean you can connect to that port to get output from the daemon and you now want whatever the "extra" information the `-r` argument provides sent to that same port (so one incoming connection sees both bits of data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per an unoffical man page at

https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments

I see

```
-r [ --raw_predictions ] arg     File to output unnormalized predictions to
```

So I think the `-r` argument is expecting a sort of `/path/to/logs/raw_preds.log` argument.

With this, you'll have "captured the optional output so it is readable." You could open a separate window and use the dev/admins old friend `tail -f /path/to/logs/raw_preds.log` to see info as it is written to the file.

If you really want it all to appear on one port, (which isn't exactly clear from your question), you'd need a separate program that can multi-plex the outputs, AND has control of your required port number. Also you'll need to be concerned about correct order of output.

IHTH.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, what you want to do it's impossibile for two reasons:

First, `bash` cannot listen on a given TCP port.
For example you cannot write a TCP server daemon in plain bash (you could use netcat for that), you can only connect() to a TCP port in bash.

Also, it is impossibile to listen on the same TCP ip:port that is already in LISTEN state by another process.